# Date("8601 format date")?

Tags: actionscript-3

The documentation for the Date() class lists several string formats that it can convert to date values. The 8601 format is not listed.

Is this accurate? Does ActionScript support parsing for 8601?

If not, how do I ask Adobe to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's supported, but I've found a way to convert to and from it [here](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2009/02/23/convert-an-iso-8601-date-string-to-from-a-native-as3-date-object/).

Comment: Thanks for the code. I'm curious why you didn't make it all static so one did not have to create and instance.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not the author of the code, I've just found it online and posted the link hoping that it will help you in some way ;)